# Why do my buttons disappear in High Sierra

Tags: cocoa, storyboard

I have 6 buttons in a stack in my MacOS storyboard.  Each button has a 30x30 .png image.  When I run under Catalina or Mojave, they layout is just what I want, but under High Sierra, some of the buttons disappear.  When I examine the `NSView.frame` and the `NSView.bounds` of the buttons, one of them has expanded to 62x30, and the others have shrunk to 0x30.

What could account for this operating system version dependency?  How would I fix it?

Comment: Apparently something has changed. Fix: add width and height constraints on the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Adding constraints to the buttons fixed it.  Thanks, Willeke.